# Função de "Curtir" sem recarregar a página?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá, boa tarde!

Eu estou tendo um problema que eu não to sabendo resolver. Eu não sei programar em JQuery ou Ajax, mas pretendo começar a aprender. Como que eu posso fazer pra fazer com que o seguinte código em PHP funcione em Ajax ou JS? Qual das duas opções é melhor pra realizar essa ação de "Curtir"?

```
<li>
      <form action="like-post.php" method="post">
      <button name="id" value="<?= $post["id"] ?>" class="like-post">Like</button>
      </form>                     
</li>
<li class="likes">
      <?php 
      echo $post["likes"];
      ?>
</li>
```

Código da página like-post:

```
include("header.php");
include("conecta.php");
include("functions.php");

   $id = $_POST['id'];
   like($conecta, $id);
   header("Location: index.php");
   die();
```

O que eu quero fazer é com que esse botão assim que clicado ele adicione mais uma curtida ao post. Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem vou te dar essa forcinha :

Podemos tirar o form, já que vai ser assíncrono.

```
<li>
  <button name="id" data-id="<?= $post["id"] ?>" class="like-post">Like</button>  
</li>
<li class="likes" id="<?= $post["id"] ?>">
    <?php 
  echo $post["likes"];
  ?>
</li>
```

Arquivo php (like-post.php):

```
<?php
     echo "123";//esse é o retorno da requisição
?>
```

Agora o Script

```
//Quando clicar nos botões com nome id
$( 'button[name="id"]' ).click(function(){
    var that = $( this );
    var valId = that.data( 'id' );

    that.prop('disabled',true);// Evitar overposting com os usuários de dedinho nervoso

    $.ajax({//requisição
        url : 'like-post.php', //url (duuhh)
        data : { id : valId }, //informações que vão no corpo da requisição
        success : ( response ) => { 
           //faça alguma coisa com o retorno, pode até ser passar o total de likes pra uma div
          console.log(response); //123
          $( '#'+valId ).html( response );// carrega dentro da <li>

        },
        error : () => {//se der erro no php
            that.prop( 'disabled',true );//deixa o usuário dedar denovo
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Mas como eu disse, eu não entendo quase nada de js (básico do básico). Como eu posso fazer pra retornar os likes pra uma determinada div?

Comment: O código que eu to usando é um echo $post['likes'] dentro de uma div com a classe "likes"

Comment: @JoãoVictorValentim editei, então `response` é `numeroDeLikes `

Comment: Desculpa, ainda não consegui entender. Dentro da parte de success no arquivo js eu preciso colocar algo? E essa variavel numeroDeLikes eu coloco dentro da div onde eu quero que apareça os likes, certo? Porque eu usei o código acima mas acaba que essa variavel não fica definida..

Comment: @JoãoVictorValentim você atribui o total de likes que vem do seu banco pra ela, editei com um valor fixo.

Comment: Ainda não consegui :/ Mas obrigado pela ajuda. Eu vou começar a dar uma estudada em Ajax e Jquery pra melhorar isso